# Unexpected identifier "object"

Tags: sentry

i have recive sentry issus, about "Unexpected identifier "object"",  its all happend in facebook brower,which version is 287 and 286,  did any one know about that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWHGR.png)